# Creating a web service in maven

Tags: maven, soap, jaxb

I'm new to maven and I'm asked to add a certain work I completed as a maven dependancy.
I did all the googling but all I found requires previous knowledge.

I need to find out how to make a simple soap web service under maven, run it on tomcat and then use jaxb to generate the client.

So can anyone point me to some reading I need to do? Thanks in advance.